# How to add additional files like "can.h" while setting up CAN communication with ESP IDF using VS code

Tags: c, embedded, esp32, can-bus, esp-idf

How can I add the necessary files such as "can.h" and others to VS code while setting up CAN communication with ESP IDF, as the official documentation only includes a "main.c" file?

I refered this documentation - [Controller Area Network (CAN) ESP-IDF Programming Guide v4.1-dev-2071-gf91080637 documentation](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/can.html#examples) [Screenshot of the webpage about CAN Programming Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRtpJ.png)

I tried TWAI protocol example and I wan unsuccessfull.

Comment: I don't understand the question... if you have those files then simply add them to your project? If you don't have them, well you need to get them. Or are you asking how to add a file to a project in VS Code?